# Get function signatures

Tags: julia

Is there a way to get a function's signatures at run time? I'd like to check the signature before calling that function. Something like:

```
exp = @sig func
if "kw" ∈ string(exp)
  func(kw=value)
end
```

Comment: `methods(func)`?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer! It works perfectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As stated in my comment, I think you're looking for `methods(func)`.

Answer (score 4):

In Julia 1.1 The signature can be obtained in the following way:

```
julia> function test(a::Integer, b::Integer, c::Integer)
       end
test (generic function with 2 methods)
julia> function extractSig(x) methods(x).ms[1].sig end
julia> extractSig(test)
Tuple{typeof(test),Integer,Integer,Integer}
```

If the symbols for the signature is needed the following base function suffices in Julia 1.1 that is

```
Base.method_argnames(methods(x).ms[1])
```

It is worth noting that the code above only consider the first definition of the function. There might be more overloaded definitions